# Energy Transfer in Telekinesis

Tags: science-based, super-powers, energy, psionics

This specific type of telekinesis is constrained in that the telekinetic can only lift what they would physically be able to lift. Somehow, they are transferring energy from their body across space, to then influence an object. How could this be justified?

Comment: I really don't think that you'll get a [tag:science-based] answer that makes sense, as telekinesis doesn't have a basis in science. You could try the [tag:magic] tag instead.

Comment: Energy transfer for telekinesis is an interesting topic to be sure and I think this question has a lot of promise. As it's written and tagged presently however, it is likely to get shut down as primarily opinion based. Could we please impose upon you to expand your question to reflect the mechanics of telekinesis in your world so we can extrapolate useful answers for you? I'd at the very least want to know why physical and mental energy are considered balanced by your practitioners and whether or not that means that lifting something heavy with the mind causes similar fatigue to physical lifts

Comment: Yeah, this is not a good fit for [tag:science-based].  You're just not going to find references or studies on this.  While this tag doesn't require the same level of verification that [tag:hard-science] does, it still needs to be something that we can describe scientifically.  You can still get answers about how one might justify the restriction though, but with different tags.  I'm adding [tag:psionics] but I will leave it to you to fix the rest.

Comment: Hi, I've voted to close this question because I believe it is too story based. This site strives to answer direct questions effectively, but this question is more of a discussion. If you would like to discuss ideas that is best done in chat, and any direct questions that may result from that discussion are very welcome here!

Comment: Hey, Just Another Evil Genius. Why don't you try placing your question in the [sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7183/sandbox-for-proposed-questions), you and us can sort out the issues there, then it'll be made ready to post here.

Answer (score 0):

**The Force!**

Yours will be only be slightly more limited. It should be a kinda force projection.

Your telekinesis only links objects through space, don't create energy from nothing. They need to exert force through their physical bodies.

As for justification? It is your universe. Telekinesis, psionics aren't rooted in our actual science (as far as my knowledge goes, top secret government research not withstanding). You can use any plausible sounding idea or just skip over it, after explaining the rules and limits of it.